# Using a Textfield with JSON instead of a ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: django, database

I am working on a project where users can roll dice pools. *A dice pool is, for example, a throw with 3 red dice, 2 blue and 1 green*. A pool is composed of several dice rolls and modifiers.

I have 3 models connected this way:

```
class DicePool(models.Model):
    # some relevant fields

class DiceRoll(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(DicePool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # plus a few more information fields with the type of die used, result, etc

class Modifier(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(DicePool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # plus about 4 more information fields
```

Now, when I load the `DicePool` history, I need to prefetch both the `DiceRoll` and `Modifier`.

I am now considering replacing the model `Modifier` with a textfield containing some JSON in `DicePool`. Just to reduce the number of database queries.

**Is it common to use a json textfield instead of a database relationship?**

**Or am I thinking this wrong and it's completely normal to do additional queries to prefetch_related everytime I load my pools?**

I personally find using a ForeignKey cleaner and it would let me do db-wise changes to data if needed. But my code is making too many db queries and I am trying to see where I can improve it.

FYI: I am using MySQL

Comment: I am not quite sure on what you are doing with prefetch.
Putting database relationships into a json textfield seems a backward step unless you have to do it from a performance point of view.  Maybe there are ways to cache some of the queries?

Comment: It also seems backward to me, but I am indeed trying to optimize performance. I am using `prefetch_related` to grab Rolls and Modifiers with 1 query each when I query the Pools. So getting the history is currently 3 queries and I was aiming at reducing it to 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it common to use a JSON text field instead of a database relationship?

I don't think so. Also, I don't believe it's advisable because (especially using MySQL that doesn't support things like JSONField) you'll end up with a text that you'd then need to parse somehow to a dict and then look up the things you want.

Personally (and I would assume that most people) would stick to FK relationships. Also, by doing `prefetch_related` or `select_related` you're already avoiding unnecessary queries.

Comment: Because pulling this history is one of the most common actions on my website, I was hoping that removing one prefetch could ease the load: going from 3 db queries (Pool+Rolls+Modifiers) to only 2 per history fetch (Pool+Rolls). It looked like 30% less queries over time, if it makes sense?

Comment: It does make sense but perhaps there are other solutions like caching the related items. Or even everything. You can also try to do the queries separately to see if there's any improvements in that sense.